# Getting an element that contains a sublist in python

Tags: python, list, substring, sublist

I'm trying to search a big list of comments and return the comments with words from the sublist.

```
sub = 'body'
submore = ['Olive', 'Personally', 'Hiding']
submore = [s.lower() for s in submore]
print submore


for s in submore:
    print "\n".join(s.lower() for s.lower(0 text.take(1000) if 
           submore.lower() in s.lower())
```

Ex. If the one comment in the text list has the sentence "Personally I would", it would print that entire comment.

The code above works for strings but not lists. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: No, the code you posted really doesn't work for strings nor lists. There are a bunch of syntax errors and undefined variables. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Combine comprehension list with the `any` builtin function:

```
comments = [...arbitrary list of comments...]
comments = [c.lower() for c in comments] # put all comments in lowercase
words = [...arbitrary list of words...]
words = [w.lower() for w in words] # same for words

matches = [c for c in comments if any(w in c for w in words)]
```